# Return html page in webmethod inside iframe multiview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Hi i want to display html page from DB using web method on anchor tag click. I get html from db but not able to display inside iframe. The html page is stored in binary format which i will be converting back. I am not able to display html page when i try to pass html through string.  Please help

```
 $('#frmDisplay').on('load', function () {
                 $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('a.anchorLink').click(function () {
                     var id = $(this).attr('id');
                   <%--  var hid = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField6.ClientID %>');
                     hid.value = id;--%>
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         url: "Amm.aspx/getlink",
                         data: "{'Id': '" + id + "'}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                             $("#frmDisplay").attr('src', data.d);
                            
                         },
                         error: function (response) {
                             alert(response.responseText);
                         }
                     });
                 });
             });

 public static string getlink(int Id)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);
            string link = "extlink";
            BookTree obj = new BookTree();
            DataSet ds = obj.getlink(Id);
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select vcFilePath from tblBookNodes where iModuleId='" + Id + "'",conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bytes = (byte[])dr["vcFilePath"];
            }
            string fileName = link.Replace(" ", "_") + ".htm";
            // DirectoryInfo strPath = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Linking/"));
            //string strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/Linking/") + fileName;
            //foreach (FileInfo file in strPath.GetFiles())
            //{
            //    file.Delete();
            //}
            string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Linking/"), fileName);
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            string html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
            sWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
            doc.Save(sWriter);
            sWriter.Close();
            string fileContents = html;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, fileContents);
            return fileContents.ToString().Trim('\n' , '\r' , '\t') ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you want to display HTML content in iframe src instead of URL.

try following way.

```
<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E" />
```

Comment: I am getting bad request error .  https://imgur.com/zf6lfQx

Comment: In your ajax response you have the following line.
$("#frmDisplay").attr('src', data.d);

So data.d should be your HTML content. and start with data:text/html;charset=utf-8,

Comment: when i change content in ajax to text/html i get something like this https://imgur.com/xkv1Yjt . Html page is not getting displayed

Comment: Can you please try with encodeURI().   `E.g. $("#frmDisplay").attr('src', data:text/html;charset=utf-8,encodeURI(data.d)); `

Comment: should i use this in success method ? because its showing syntax error

Comment: Yes, you can. maybe a double quote missing. fix syntax error and check

`E.g. $("#frmDisplay").attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+encodeURI(data.d));`

Comment: Its working but whole is not getting displayed. only some part is displayed. but in the folder i get the whole page.     https://imgur.com/nY7UIXm

Comment: Great. Now there is a possibility to some syntax or encode string related. You can check with inspect element (F12) and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, although not in .NET, I was able to render HTML returned from an api using `srcdoc` attribute of an `<iframe>` as follows:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html><body>Hello, <b>world</b>.</body></html>"></iframe>
```

source:  [documentation](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/render+html+in+iframe)